# What is in my NSArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an `NSArray` that has been populated by:

```
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"http://website/getinfo.php?dept=", dept];
NSArray *arrayDetail = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
```

The SQL database is empty but following the call *arrayDetail* has 'one object' in it but I have no idea what this object is.

I have tried:

```
NSLog(@"value - %@", [arrayDetail objectAtIndex:0]);
```

The `NSLog` displayed is "value - "

I have tried:

```
if ([arrayDetail objectAtIndex:0]  == (id)[NSNull null])
{
   NSLog(@"null");
}
else
{
 //do other stuff
}
```

but it skips over to 'do other stuff'.

I have also tried:

```
if ([[arrayDetail objectAtIndex:0]  isEqualToString:@""])
```

but again it skips to 'do other stuff'.

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

Following the advice from below I have tried:

```
 NSLog(@"value - %@", [arrayDetail class])
```

with the response:

> value - __NSCFConstantString

Comment: What about breakpoint and `NSLog(@"%@", [arrayDetail.lastObject class])`?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/19059374/716216

Comment: Please use NSLog(@"%@", arrayDetail); then you can check any value on 0 index.

Comment: If you do `NSLog(@"%@", arrayDetail);` it should print out `(` and `)` characters with the array elements in-between.  If not, then you probably received a `nil` value back from the array create operation because the URL was bogus.  My guess is that the URL is bogus.

Comment: This is the result: value - (
    ""
) . I know the URL is not bogus as I get the correct results when data is in the SQL database.

Comment: @SandeepAgrawal - see previous comment

Comment: @RichardGriffiths your approach can't work, the database is not delivering a string representation of NSArray but whatever else. You'll need to parse the result and create an NSArray from that.

Comment: If there is data in the database it works fine. If there is not the return is (""). I think the issue is how initWithContentsOfURL deals with a return of ("").

Comment: Your above result would indicate you're receiving an NSString of zero length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Might contain a escape character. & check for the NSArray - NSLog(@"Res %@",arrayDetail);

Try this Out :

```
if ([arrayDetail objectAtIndex:0]  == (id)[NSNull null] || [[arrayDetail objectAtIndex:0]length] < 1)
{
   NSLog(@"null");
}
else
{
 //do other stuff
}
```

Comment: This does the job - thanks. I am still would like to know the root of the problem (i.e. what is it that is in the array) but this works so great.

Answer (score 2):

Only if your web service delivers a string representation of an array produced by the writeToURL:atomically: method the array will contain anything useful.

Since usually this does not happen from web services, you will have chunk but no content. Probably it is not even initialized but nil. And thus showing the behavior you get.

Answer (score 1):

check

```
if ([[arrayDetail objectAtIndex:0]  isEqualToString:@""])
```

instead of

```
if ([[observationsArrayClass objectAtIndex:0]  isEqualToString:@""])
```

Let me know your output.Why have you used observationsArrayClass when your output gets stored in arrayDetail?

Comment: ok, so have you checked null and empty string both? check if there are any spaces in the object. Check the url in browser and let me know

Comment: When I check the URL in the browser I get  ( "" )

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/initWithContentsOfURL%3a) for `initWithContentsOfURL:`:

> [It] Returns [a] nil if the location can’t be opened or if the contents of the location can’t be parsed into an array.